# VPN PPTP disconnects after certain time

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, vpn

My VPN keeps disconnecting. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit HP workstation.

The VPN connection just dies out after a random period of time no matter if I'm using it or not. I've tried a few things that I've found out either here or on some forums but it just keeps failing. I've tried disabling any kind of compression.

here is the log from `/var/log/syslog`

`Aug 17 23:55:55 ST-A2300 NetworkManager[1051]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: started (4)
Aug 17 23:55:55 ST-A2300 dbus[961]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Aug 17 23:55:55 ST-A2300 dbus[961]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug 17 23:56:04 ST-A2300 ntpdate[17681]: no server suitable for synchronization found
Aug 17 23:56:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Request received.
Aug 17 23:56:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 6 'Echo-Reply'
Aug 17 23:57:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Request received.
Aug 17 23:57:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 6 'Echo-Reply'
Aug 17 23:58:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Request received.
Aug 17 23:58:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 6 'Echo-Reply'
Aug 17 23:58:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug 17 23:59:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Request received.
Aug 17 23:59:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 6 'Echo-Reply'
Aug 17 23:59:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
Aug 18 00:00:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Request received.
Aug 18 00:00:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 6 'Echo-Reply'
Aug 18 00:01:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Request received.
Aug 18 00:01:51 ST-A2300 pptp[17618]: nm-pptp-service-17596 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 6 'Echo-Reply'
Aug 18 00:02:14 ST-A2300 kernel: [36049.055991] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 18 00:02:14 ST-A2300 kernel: [36049.056000] ata4.00: failed command: SMART
Aug 18 00:02:14 ST-A2300 kernel: [36049.056010] ata4.00: cmd b0/d0:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 16 pio 512 in
Aug 18 00:02:14 ST-A2300 kernel: [36049.056010]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Aug 18 00:02:14 ST-A2300 kernel: [36049.056014] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Aug 18 00:02:14 ST-A2300 kernel: [36049.056021] ata4: hard resetting link
Aug 18 00:02:18 ST-A2300 kernel: [36052.796159] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 18 00:02:18 ST-A2300 kernel: [36052.797268] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
Aug 18 00:02:18 ST-A2300 kernel: [36052.812153] ata4: EH complete
Aug 18 00:02:25 ST-A2300 kernel: [36060.056712] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 18 00:02:25 ST-A2300 kernel: [36060.056721] ata4.00: failed command: SMART
Aug 18 00:02:25 ST-A2300 kernel: [36060.056730] ata4.00: cmd b0/da:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 20
Aug 18 00:02:25 ST-A2300 kernel: [36060.056730]          res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Aug 18 00:02:25 ST-A2300 kernel: [36060.056735] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Aug 18 00:02:25 ST-A2300 kernel: [36060.056742] ata4: hard resetting link
Aug 18 00:02:29 ST-A2300 kernel: [36064.128892] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 18 00:02:30 ST-A2300 kernel: [36064.183147] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
Aug 18 00:02:30 ST-A2300 udisksd[2522]: Error performing housekeeping for drive /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/ST3000DM001_1CH166_W1F3AACG: Error updating SMART data: sk_disk_smart_status: Input/output error (udisks-error-quark, 0)
Aug 18 00:02:30 ST-A2300 kernel: [36064.196912] ata4: EH complete`

Comment: You really  shouldn't be using `PPTP`, as it's old and insecure. If possible try switching to `OpenVPN`.